# Weird youtube logo today

Tags: firefox, 15.10, youtube, ubuntu-gnome

Anyone else see the youtube logo like this today?

[image: logo1]

It suddenly became some weird blue thing. Is it just me?

Comment: YouTube changed it to support Global Warming efforts. They do this pretty frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only you, with me too or with everyone on earth who using YouTube. As A.J.Ruckman said it's suppoting Global Warming .
[Here](https://www.youtube.com/user/YouTube) is the channel.

Comment: OK, thanks. Firefox was real sluggish yesterday I was worried it was a virus or something

Comment: @stepb YouTube is belong to Google now so changing logo  happens frequently.

Comment: Climate Change not Global Warming - stuff just doesn't get hotter u know....

Comment: Global Warming will make Climate Change @Wilf